# Executing same select for update without order by with multiple results in different transactions causing deadlocks

Tags: sql, postgresql, deadlock, pessimistic-locking

Transaction A:

```
select * from table_a where field_a = 'A' for update;
```

Transaction B:

```
select * from table_a where field_a = 'A' for update;
```

If these transactions are ran at about the same time, can it cause a deadlock?

The queries are expected to return multiple results.

I was thinking that maybe underneath, it was locking the results one by one, and since the order was not specified, there is a chance that the locking might occur in different orders, that will cause a dead lock.

Is this possible?

Comment: You are correct; this can cause a deadlock, and you need an `ORDER BY` to avoid it.